# Prove that two consecutive square free numbers can have arbitrarily large gaps

Tags: number-theory

I want to the following theorem:

> The two consecutive square free numbers have arbitrarily large gaps.

I tried to prove through definition directly and tried to find a lower bound for the gap of two consecutive square free numbers. However, I failed in this way since I did not figure out it.

Does anyone have a hint for this proof, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Suppose you want a gap of at least $4$. Find $x$ s.t. $x \equiv 0 \pmod{2^2}, x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3^2}, x+2 \equiv 0 \pmod{5^2}$. Can you generalise for larger gaps?

Comment: Well, I did see this hint from some other reference, but I did not quite get it.

Comment: @Scorpio19891119 Do you see why that gives a gap of at least $4$? Have you tried to do the same for larger gaps?

Comment: @Scorpio19891119 As you asked for hints, I don't want to give too much of the solution away, so it would help if you highlight exactly what you do not get/understand about the hint, especially since you have already seen the exact same hint from somewhere else. (It would help in future if you mentioned that as well)