# Large gap between two consecutive square-free numbers

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $q_n$ denote the $n$-th square-free number. By [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) (see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550831/prove-that-two-consecutive-square-free-numbers-can-have-arbitrarily-large-gaps)), it is not difficult to show that there is arbitrarily large gap between two consecutive square-free numbers, i.e., $\limsup_{n\to\infty}(q_{n+1}-q_n)=\infty$. How to prove the stronger bound?
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{q_{n+1}-q_n}{\log n/\log\log n}\geq \frac{1}{2}.$$
I don't how to get started, thanks for any help.

Edit: This is an exercise (Exercise 2.20) from A.J. Hildebrand's [An introduction to analytic number theory](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/main.pdf).

Comment: what is your source for the problem/conjecture?

Comment: @WillJagy It's an exercise (Exercise 2.20) from A.J. Hildebrand's online [lecture notes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/main.pdf).

Comment: @XiangYu See appendix 1 of http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~grg/papers/USsieve.pdf .

Answer (score 1):

> How to prove the stronger bound?

By estimating the index where the constructed gap between successive squarefree numbers occurs. Since the denominator, $\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$ increases with $n$ for $n > e^e$, overestimating the index underestimates the quotient.

Thus, if to construct a gap of size $\geqslant g$ we find $m$ satisfying the congruences
$$m \equiv -k \pmod{p_k^2}$$
for $1 \leqslant k < g$, by the Chinese remainder theorem there is a unique solution satisfying
$$0 < m < (p_{g-1}\#)^2$$
(where $x\#$ is the primorial of $x$, i.e. the product of all primes not exceeding $x$). Then we have a gap $\geqslant g$ between $q_n$ and $q_{n+1}$, where $n = Q(m)$ is the number of squarefree numbers $\leqslant m$.

We know that $Q(m) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}m + O(\sqrt{m})$, but that doesn't give anything beyond the trivial $n = Q(m) \leqslant m$. We must, however, assume $g \geqslant 4$ to ensure $n > e^e$, so that our overestimating of $n$ certainly doesn't increase the quotient. The bound $n < (p_{g-1}\#)^2 < (p_g\#)^2$ yields
$$\log n < 2 \log (p_g\#) = 2 \vartheta(p_g)$$
and hence
\begin{align}
\frac{q_{n+1} - q_n}{\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}} &\geqslant \frac{g}{\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}} \\
&> \frac{g}{\frac{2\vartheta(p_g)}{\log \vartheta(p_g) + \log 2}} \\
&\sim \frac{g}{\frac{2p_g}{\log p_g}} \\
&\sim \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
using the prime number theorem for $\vartheta(p_g) \sim p_g \sim g\log g$ and $\log \vartheta(p_g) = \log p_g + O(1) \sim \log g$.

For the following sharper estimate
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{q_{n+1} - q_n}{\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}} \geqslant \frac{\pi^2}{12}$$
one uses the fact that each of the small primes produces not only one non-squarefree number in the gap but approximately $g/p^2$. Thus let $c > 1$ arbitrary, and choose $r$ such that
$$\prod_{\rho = 1}^{r} \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p_{\rho}^2}\biggr) < c\cdot \frac{6}{\pi^2}\,.$$
Then, for sufficiently large $g$ every sequence of $g$ consecutive integers contains fewer than
$$c^2\frac{6}{\pi^2}\cdot g$$
integers that aren't divisible by any of the $p_{\rho}^2$, $1 \leqslant \rho \leqslant r$.

Hence to produce a gap of size at least $g$ (for sufficiently large $g$) we don't need $g-1$ primes,
$$A(g) = r + \biggl\lfloor c^2\frac{6}{\pi^2}g\biggr\rfloor$$
primes suffice. Then in the computation above we can replace $p_g$ with $p_{A(g)}$, yielding
$$\frac{q_{n+1}-q_n}{\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}} > \frac{g}{2\frac{\vartheta(p_{A(g)})}{\log \vartheta(p_{A(g)})}} \sim \frac{g}{2 A(g)} \sim \frac{\pi^2}{12c^2}\,.$$
Since $c > 1$ was arbitrary,
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{q_{n+1}-q_n}{\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}} \geqslant \frac{\pi^2}{12}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about how large that ratio could stay. I had it print out only when the ratio exceeded 1.5. Does not seem to be dying out. The later part of that exercise says prove the limsup is at least $\pi^2/12 \approx 0.822467$ From what I am seeing, a limsup between 1 and 2 seems a good bet. Probably hard to prove, though.

First, just when the ratio increases:

```
 n = 4   old q  3  q 5  ratio  0.1712120437515166    gap  2
 n = 5   old q  5  q 6  ratio  0.2356168135275511    gap  1
 n = 6   old q  6  q 7  ratio  0.2956839724294714    gap  1
 n = 7   old q  7  q 10  ratio  0.9764671388072846    gap  3
 n = 17   old q  23  q 26  ratio  1.103425220291327    gap  3
 n = 32   old q  47  q 51  ratio  1.437072374330929    gap  4
 n = 151   old q  241  q 246  ratio  1.608142099431302    gap  5
 n = 516   old q  843  q 849  ratio  1.760024446369004    gap  6
```

Now, ratio larger than 1.5

```
 n = 151   old q  241  q 246  ratio  1.608142099431302    gap  5
 n = 516   old q  843  q 849  ratio  1.760024446369004    gap  6
 n = 1026   old q  1679  q 1685  ratio  1.675782937474057    gap  6
 n = 1756   old q  2887  q 2893  ratio  1.615152343691931    gap  6
 n = 2208   old q  3623  q 3629  ratio  1.590625635457252    gap  6
 n = 3071   old q  5045  q 5051  ratio  1.556608495338398    gap  6
 n = 13392   old q  22019  q 22026  ratio  1.658619700318701    gap  7
 n = 14985   old q  24646  q 24653  ratio  1.647791097638391    gap  7
 n = 18804   old q  30922  q 30929  ratio  1.626378938461883    gap  7
 n = 28995   old q  47671  q 47678  ratio  1.587166663694555    gap  7
 n = 33718   old q  55446  q 55453  ratio  1.573982134381624    gap  7
 n = 34728   old q  57119  q 57126  ratio  1.571431499337303    gap  7
 n = 44650   old q  73446  q 73453  ratio  1.550075102998279    gap  7
 n = 45501   old q  74847  q 74854  ratio  1.54849635050823    gap  7
 n = 58776   old q  96674  q 96681  ratio  1.527433347355694    gap  7
 n = 64310   old q  105771  q 105778  ratio  1.520178814511105    gap  7
 n = 73964   old q  121666  q 121673  ratio  1.509052248661901    gap  7
 n = 74071   old q  121846  q 121853  ratio  1.50893818425337    gap  7
 n = 131965   old q  217069  q 217077  ratio  1.674107764035864    gap  8
 n = 408142   old q  671345  q 671353  ratio  1.584428949113135    gap  8
 n = 502653   old q  826823  q 826831  ratio  1.569036523505159    gap  8
 n = 664314   old q  1092746  q 1092755  ratio  1.742561268994944    gap  9
 n = 867735   old q  1427369  q 1427377  ratio  1.530225943242189    gap  8
 n = 1274859   old q  2097047  q 2097055  ratio  1.50414070948736    gap  8
 n = 4387186   old q  7216617  q 7216626  ratio  1.605004820261783    gap  9
 n = 5392319   old q  8870023  q 8870033  ratio  1.768248678666427    gap  10
 n = 8741561   old q  14379270  q 14379279  ratio  1.560603965676062    gap  9
 n = 13760650   old q  22635346  q 22635355  ratio  1.532852419427845    gap  9
 n = 15086919   old q  24816973  q 24816982  ratio  1.527358881812587    gap  9
 n = 15227282   old q  25047845  q 25047854  ratio  1.526808447544024    gap  9
^C
```

Worth noting that the actual $q_{n+1} - q_n$ are quite small, near the end of this output just 9 or 10. Eh, shorter output, I told it to keep going forever and just print when the gap size increases. Here it is so far:

```
 n = 4   old q  3  q 5  ratio  0.1712120437515166    gap  2
 n = 7   old q  7  q 10  ratio  0.9764671388072846    gap  3
 n = 32   old q  47  q 51  ratio  1.437072374330929    gap  4
 n = 151   old q  241  q 246  ratio  1.608142099431302    gap  5
 n = 516   old q  843  q 849  ratio  1.760024446369004    gap  6
 n = 13392   old q  22019  q 22026  ratio  1.658619700318701    gap  7
 n = 131965   old q  217069  q 217077  ratio  1.674107764035864    gap  8
 n = 664314   old q  1092746  q 1092755  ratio  1.742561268994944    gap  9
 n = 5392319   old q  8870023  q 8870033  ratio  1.768248678666427    gap  10
```

This last version is extended at https://oeis.org/A020754  and 
https://oeis.org/A020754/b020754.txt